# Macro that imports 100 .txt files into multiple sheets in excel in true chronological order

Tags: vba, excel, import

Hoping I can get some advice regarding my VBA code, I have a 100 text files numbered **1_OUT_IX_-500.TXT, 2_OUT_IX_-490.TXT** and so on till 101_OUT_IX_500.TXT, so far I haven't had any luck with regards to finding a macro that imports the .TXT files into an excel work book in a chronological order i.e. **1_OUT_IX_-500.TXT, 2_OUT_IX_-490.TXT** and so on instead of **1_OUT_IX_-500.TXT, 10_OUT_IX_-410.TXT** and change the name of the work sheet to that of the imported files.

I've got a macro below and it seems to do most of it ***but*** I've noticed that some of the imported data is inaccurate and more importantly they are not in a true chronological order, this is important as I create a summary sheet from the values in AO2:AQ2 in a new worksheet.

so basically any help with either modifying my macro or suggests of a new macro are welcome. honestly any help is truly appreciated, and thank you in advance for taking the time to read this, again any help is truly appreciated.

Thank you

```
    Sub MacroLoop()
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 101
strFile = Dir("C:\Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ig=520\Ic=340\340_TXT\" & i & "_*.TXT")
If strFile <> "" Then
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & "C:\Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ig=520\Ic=340\340_TXT\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = strFile
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1251
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
ws.Name = strFile
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion for getting the files in chronological order...

1) Use an incrementer to go from 1 to whatever your high values is (100 in your case above)

2) Loop through and add in your incrementer into the Dir statement (i in my example below)

```
strFile = Dir("C:\Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ig=520\Ic=340\340_TXT\" & i & "_*.TXT")
```

3) Grab data from that file as you normally do, without calling the Dir function again, instead looping to your next incrementer.

```
Psuedocode
For I = 1 to numberOfFilesInDirectory
    strFile = Dir("C:\Users\Abubakar Adan\JSIM\Ig=520\Ic=340\340_TXT\" & I & "_*.TXT")
    if fileExists(strFile) then
        'do your file processing
    endif
next i
```

Another option would be to get the files initially with a set standard, such as 3 (or 4) place digits at the beginning.  So, file names would be "0001_xxx", "0002_xxx", etc.  Then your code as above works fine.

As for the issue with incorrect data, cannot give a suggestion to you because we don't know what sort of issues you are seeing and what the file looks like.

Comment: All-round great answer! +1! Maybe just detail a little bit more on how/where to implement the loop with this new directive. It's pretty obvious when you have some experience, but maybe not to apprentices.

Comment: Added some psuedoCode to show the process.  Though I don't go into great detail (for example, the FileExists method needs researched), it gives an idea of how to make it work.

Comment: Looks fabulous; though maybe replace `fileExists(strFile)` with `strFile <> ""`.

Comment: @BernardSaucier, that works too.  The OP can figure out which one he likes.

Comment: @BernardSaucier Thank you guys for the great answer, I'm quite new to vba, currently trying to run the code but the macro for importing the text files doesnt seem to be working any ideas? I've changed my orginial post to show the code I'm using

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to be working", what do you mean?  Can you step through the code to see where it is going wrong?

Comment: @APrough it was my fault I did not input the correct file path changed that now and your code works beautifully thank you very much!!!